# What is Android BrowserFrame and how do I use it?

Tags: android, android-webview

I've found a class mentioned in various forums called android.webkit.BrowserFrame.  That class has a method stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString that I really need to use.  I can't find anything in the docs about this class.  What is it and how do I use it?

And if I can't use it, doesn't anyone know how I can mimic that function?  I need an immediate return from javascript, can't go the interface route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is it and how do I use it?

There is no such class in the Android SDK. It is a private class inside the firmware.

> And if I can't use it, doesn't anyone know how I can mimic that function?

You can't. It is a native method.

Comment: I can't use that method.  But there has to be a way to duplicate its function.

Comment: @btate: Only by writing your own operating system. It will be far simpler for you to fix your app, to be able to execute JavaScript and get results asynchronously. Perhaps you should consider asking a StackOverflow question for assistance on that instead.